# looping through an array by slices, not each item

Tags: php

I have an array of potentially 1000s of items that I need to feed to and API that can handle 10 at a time. So, can I do something like this?

```
$data = [ ... ];
$start = 0;
$step = 10;

foreach (api_function(array_slice($data, $start, $step))){
   $start += $step;
}
```

Using Nigel Ren's answer the final code looks like this:

```
$results = BC_cust_query($qlist, true);

$start = 0;
$step = 10;
$stop = count($results);

while ($start < $stop){
   print_r(array_slice($results, $start, $step));
   $start += $step;
}
```

Where print_r() will be replace by the API call

Comment: [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) might be better than array_slice. Also note that you can't use `foreach()` on a function like that.

Comment: @aynber `array_chunk()` would create a copy of the already big array, using more memory than necessary, but it would probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to keep repeating the call to the API for each slice, until there is no more data left (check the start against the length of the array).  Assuming it returns blank, some thing like

```
$data = [ ... ];
$start = 0;
$step = 10;

$countData = count($data);
// Fetch block of data whilst some data to fetch.
while ($start < $countData &&
        $dataBlock = api_function(array_slice($data, $start, $step))){
    // Loop over this block
    foreach ( $dataBlock as $dataItem) {
        // Process item
    }
    // Move onto next block
    $start += $step;
}
```

or use a for loop...

```
$data = [ ... ];
$step = 10;

$countData = count($data);
// Fetch block of data whilst some data to fetch.
for ($start = 0;$start < $countData; $start += $step) {
    $dataBlock = api_function(array_slice($data, $start, $step));
    // Loop over this block
    foreach ( $dataBlock as $dataItem) {
        // Process item
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks good. You don't need to put the `$dataBlock = api_function(array_slice($data, $start, $step))` bit in the `while` expression, you can just put it inside `{ .... }`, unless you think that `api_function()` might return `false` when it fails. I doubt that, but it is possible.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I have no idea what api_function does, but the point is valid.  It's up to OP to make that decision I think.

Comment: Yes, it is. We don't know what it does.